# java stop no response and errors

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using apache-poi to parse a lot of word documents. I have the following code.

```
URL u = new URL(fileName);

// given a url open a connection
URLConnection c = u.openConnection();

// set the connection timeout to 5 seconds
c.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);

System.out.println("Start to parse DOC file.");
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(u.openStream());
System.out.println("File opened.");
```

I run this code in a loop, open the word document and parse the document. Sometimes the code stopped at `new POIFSFileSystem(u.openStream())` without any warnings and errors for several hours. I have to restart the program.

What's the possible reason?

Comment: Huge file, Locking could be anything.

Comment: You should change your logging to indicate which file is being worked on, and see if you see a pattern. Is it always the same file giving you problems, for example.

Comment: Every time it is not the same file. The file size is not huge.

Comment: Do you close POIFSFileSystem ?

Comment: If you just write from the stream to disk, without any POI code, does that hang too? And does it fail with NPOIFSFileSystem?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll test one by one.